# reading taps on titleview field iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem with reading taps on navigation bar (I need to open dropdown menu by tapping on title field, just like in telegram and etc. but not in swift)
I know that basically its unreadable, and already've tried with taprecognizer, but it didn't work for me any good. 
Now my menu opens with rightbarbutton - that's ugly.
How can I deal with it?

Now string that drops menu (placed in viewDidLoad) looks like:

```
navbar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"navbar" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navigationTitleTapGestureAction:)];
```

and a part that declares button:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[navbar <<...a few more buttons...>>];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

EDIT: additional code from the comments:

```
- (IBAction)navigationTitleTapGestureAction:(id)sender {
   automaticDisappearanceCanceled_ = YES; 
   if (menuToolbarVisible_) { 
      [self hideMenuAnimated:YES]; 
   } 
   else { 
      [self showMenuAnimated:YES]; 
   }
 }

 - (void)showMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated { 
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    self.toolbarTopLayoutConstraint.constant = 0.f;
    self.menuToolbar.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? ToolbarMenuAnimationDuration : 0.f animations:^{ 
       [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
   } completion: ^(BOOL finished) { 
   }];
   menuToolbarVisible_ = YES; 
 }

- (void)hideMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated { 
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
   self.toolbarTopLayoutConstraint.constant = -ToolbarMenuHeight;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? ToolbarMenuAnimationDuration : 0.f animations: ^{ 
       [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
       self.menuToolbar.hidden = YES; 
  }]; 
  menuToolbarVisible_ = NO; 
 }
```

Comment: add some additional code or UI what u faced

Comment: or show your code of `navigationTitleTapGestureAction`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik code of this selector: '- (IBAction)navigationTitleTapGestureAction:(id)sender {
    automaticDisappearanceCanceled_ = YES;
    if (menuToolbarVisible_) {
        [self hideMenuAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [self showMenuAnimated:YES];
    }
}'

Comment: can you show the code of `showMenuAnimated:YES` and `hideMenuAnimated:YES`

Comment: - (void)showMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    
    self.toolbarTopLayoutConstraint.constant = 0.f;
    self.menuToolbar.hidden = NO;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? ToolbarMenuAnimationDuration : 0.f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        
    }];
    menuToolbarVisible_ = YES;
}

Comment: (void)hideMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    
    self.toolbarTopLayoutConstraint.constant = -ToolbarMenuHeight;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? ToolbarMenuAnimationDuration : 0.f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.menuToolbar.hidden = YES;
    }];
    menuToolbarVisible_ = NO;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far is I know you just want to get taps on the text on the center of navigation bar you can do this by adding a UIButton in the titleView like this :-

```
UIButton *centerButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44.0, 44.0)];
[centerButton setTitle:@"Center" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[centerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
self.navigationItem.titleView=centerButton;
```

Comment: your solution works awesome just like "cmd+c => cmd+v", cheers!

Comment: @Chickenfresh: but do you understand what it does and how it solved your problem?

Comment: @Koen, yes, I've been trying to set up rightbar item when I needed titleView. Actually IOS dev's documentation for obj-c for me is something threw into pieces over the internet and contains a lot of outdated topics